# Are the limits of Euclidean spaces Hilbert spaces?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, limits-colimits

Consider each Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a topological vector space. I wondered what I get by taking $n \to \infty$ in the category of topological vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$.

There are really two kinds of limit here; the direct limit and the inverse limit. By letting the inclusion maps $f_n : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be defined as $f_n(x_1, \cdots, x_n) = (x_1, \cdots, x_n, 0)$, I concluded that the direct limit is the real vector space with countably infinite dimension, denoted by $\mathbb{R}^\infty$, endowed with the box topology. By letting the projection maps $g_n : \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be defined as $g_n(x_1, \cdots, x_n, x_{n+1}) = (x_1, \cdots, x_n)$, I concluded that the inverse limit is $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ endowed with the product topology.

Does this mean $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ and $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ are Hilbert spaces? That is, are there inner products that induces the topologies?

Comment: Do you require Hilbert spaces to be complete? Also, the question makes no sense as stated since you defined a topology on the limit but not a metric. Are you asking for a homeomorphism to a Hilbert space?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Kadec_theorem) is relevant. Note that nor $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ nor $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ with product topology can be equipped with a norm while keeping the same linear structure. So they're Hilbert spaces only topologically.

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike I'm asking whether there are inner product structures for them whose induced norm induces the metric that induces their topology.

Comment: Sorry, I mean that $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is a Hilbert space topologically (i.e. homeomorphic to one), $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of one.

Comment: This question doesn't seem very well posed. It (usually) massively depends on the *diagram* what the inverse or direct limits will be. You haven't specified any diagrams, just merely said they should involve linear maps. It also matters in what category you'd like to compute the (co)limits: in Sets? In Top? In Vect? ??

Comment: Neither the product $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ (limit of $\mathbb R^n)$ nor the copodruct $\mathbb R^\infty$ in the category TVS (of topological vector spaces and continuous linear maps) is (isomorphic in TVS to) a Hilbert space: The product does not have continuous norms and the coproduct is countable dimensional.